# OrderBy in constructor

Tags: c#, .net

I am deriving the ObservableCollection and desire to have a where condition aswell as the order by in my constructor.

The following works fine with the condition but I cannot do it with orderby :(

```
public class CustomCollection<TModel> : ObservableCollection<TModel> where TModel : EntityBaseClass
{
    private readonly Func<TModel, bool> _condition;

    public CustomCollection(ObservableCollection<TModel> source, Func<TModel, bool> condition)
        : base(source.Where(condition))
    {
        _condition = condition;
    }
}
```

What I tried is to extend the constructor with the following parameter

```
Func<TModel, TModel> orderby
```

and change the : base call to

```
: base(source.Where(condition).OrderBy(orderby))
```

This builds without problem, 
but when I try to call this like so:

```
new CustomCollection<TestClass>(SourceCollection, x => x.Price == 2.50, x => x.SortOrder);
```

I am receiving the following message.

"Cannot convert expression type 'string' to return type 'TestClass'".

Which kinda makes sense since my condition is of

```
Func<TModel, TModel> condition
```

which is the TestClass specified twice, when I look at the of OrderBy implementation I can see TSource and TKey, but how am I able to specify the TKey in my case?

Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a new generic argument to represent the type that the `orderby`'s selector maps to.  The selector in your case is forced to select something of the same type as the model object itself, but you don't actually want that.

```
public class CustomCollection<TModel, TSortKey> : ObservableCollection<TModel>
    where TModel : EntityBaseClass
{
    private readonly Func<TModel, bool> _condition;
    private readonly Func<TModel, TSortKey> sortSelector;

    public CustomCollection(ObservableCollection<TModel> source,
        Func<TModel, bool> condition,
        Func<TModel, TSortKey> sortSelector)
        : base(source.Where(condition).OrderBy(sortSelector))
    {
        _condition = condition;
        this.sortSelector = sortSelector;
    }
}
```

Comment: With this I am forced to initialize with new CustomCollection<TestClass, TestClass>(....); or?

Comment: @RandRandom The second type argument should be the type of whatever you're sorting on, not what your model is (unless that's what you're sorting on).  You can also create generic factory methods, rather than using the constructor, so that you can take advantage of generic type inference.

Comment: Could you provide a solution of your mentioned alternative (generic factory) ?

Comment: @RandRandom I think you can figure it out on your own.  All you need to do is create a static method that has the same generic arguments as this class, and the same parameters as the constructor; it's implementation needs to be nothing but passing the values to this constructor and returning that value.

Comment: Would it help, if I said pretty please? Because I didnt really get what you meant sry.

Comment: @RandRandom look into what a [factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx) is. The method signature should be something like `public static Create<TModel, TSortKey>(ObservableCollection<TModel> source,
        Func<TModel, bool> condition,
        Func<TModel, TSortKey> sortSelector)`. The advantage is that the C# type system can then infer the types involved.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `orderby` `Func` to return `object`:

```
Func<TModel, object> orderBy
```

The [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is smart enough to work in such an instance (assuming your key implements `IComparable`). The biggest downside to this, compared to adding another generic type like Servy's solution, is that you can't specify a strongly-typed `IComparer<>` to go along with it (you'd have to specify an `IComparer<object>` that casts before comparing).

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain? The downvote came surprisingly fast. Faster than I'd expect a human to be able to - certainly faster than a human could read my answer and know if it deserved a downvote.